# Log SQL and stored procedures calls with Sybase and Java

Tags: logging, jdbc, sybase, java.util.logging

I am using Sybase with Java. I want to log which SQL statements and which stored procedure calls are actually sent to the database. I am using JConnect 4, the Maven dependency is `com.sybase:jconn4`.

I have configured the following loggers to log at the `ALL` level. According to http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0707110/doc/html/adh1375869748274.html this should be enough.

```
private static Logger log1 = Logger.getLogger(SybDriver.class.getName());
private static Logger log2 = Logger.getLogger(SybConnection.class.getName());
private static Logger log3 = Logger.getLogger(SybStatement.class.getName());
private static Logger log4 = Logger.getLogger(SybPreparedStatement.class.getName());
private static Logger log5 = Logger.getLogger(SybResultSet.class.getName());

static {
    log1.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    log2.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    log3.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    log4.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    log5.setLevel(Level.ALL);
}
```

However, I don't see any database calls. I just see statements like these:

```
Apr 28, 2021 11:41:16 AM com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement setQueryTimeout
FINER: Dr127_Co1_Ps36 setQueryTimeout(int = [0])
Apr 28, 2021 11:41:16 AM com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement executeQuery
FINE: Dr127_Co1_Ps36 executeQuery()
Apr 28, 2021 11:41:16 AM com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybResultSet next
FINE: Dr127_Co1_Ps36_Rs76 next()
```

Am I missing some configuration?

Comment: Try setting the root logger `""` to all.  Is your console handler set to ALL?  Any luck with using the DriverManager.setLogWriter or DataSource.setLogWriter?

Comment: sysaudit should provide you this functionality on the server side, without making mods to Java.